# No Movement in ship

Tags: python, class, methods, python-import

When i run the game. The ship is drawn in the middle of the screen however when I press the arrow keys to move the ship nothing happens. When i press *q* to quit the game that does work so the *keydown* method does seem to working. I believe the issue has something to do with *ship_movement* not being utilized the way i want too. Any ideas?

Main File -

```
import pygame 
from settings import Settings
from ship_test import Ship
from ship_movement import User_input_responses

class Alien_Invasion:


    def __init__(self):
        
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.movement = User_input_responses()
        #screen
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width , self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption(("Alien Invader"))
        self.bg_color = self.settings.bg_color

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.ship = Ship(self)

        
            
    def update_screen(self):
        pygame.display.flip()
        self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()





    def game(self):
        while True:
            self.movement.user_input_reactions()
            self.ship.ship_movement()
            self.update_screen()
            self.clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game_launcher = Alien_Invasion()
    game_launcher.game()
```

Movement File -

```
import pygame
import sys
from ship_test import Ship

class User_input_responses:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ship = Ship()
        


    def user_input_reactions(self):

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self.keydown(event)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self.keyup(event)
                
    
    def keydown(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True

        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True

        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.ship.moving_up = True

        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.ship.moving_down = True
        
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
```

Ship file -

```
import pygame 
from settings import Settings

class Ship:

    def __init__(self, game=""):
        

        if game:
            self.screen = game.screen
            self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
            self.image = pygame.image.load("images/ship.bmp")
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center
            self.x = float(self.rect.x)
            self.y = float(self.rect.y) 

        self.settings = Settings()
        
    
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False
         

    def ship_movement(self):
        
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
            

        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:

            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed
        
        if self.moving_down and self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:

            self.y += self.settings.ship_speed

        if self.moving_up and self.rect.top > 0:
            self.y -= self.settings.ship_speed

        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y


    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

Comment: In `User_input_responses.__init__` you are instantiating a new `Ship()` object. This ship object is totally unrelated to your other ship object instantiated in `Alien_Invasion.__init__`. Any changes like `self.ship.moving_right = True` within `User_input_responses` will not be reflected in the other ship object. Instead, it seems you want a single `Ship()` object instance that you pass around to different classes/functions which all mutate the same underlying ship object as needed.

Comment: Basically, the issue is that right now you have two ship objects - one which you draw/render but don't update, and the other which you update but don't draw/render.

Comment: I see what your saying. I thought of just importing `Ship` from my main file  into my movement file but i already import `User_input_responses` from my movement file into my main file so I get a double import error. I think my best course is to combine my movement file with my main file to erase the need to access the `Ship()`  object twice. I was trying to keep my main file as short as possible but moving the movement to a different file is messing my code up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your files the same. The simplest change would be to just have your `User_input_responses` class' constructor take a ship object parameter:

```
class User_input_responses:

    def __init__(self, ship):
        self.ship = ship
```

And then in `Alien_Invasion`:

```
class Alien_Invasion:

    def __init__(self):
        
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.movement = User_input_responses(self.ship)
        #screen
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width , self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption(("Alien Invader"))
        self.bg_color = self.settings.bg_color

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```